# How can one upgrade Ubuntu 19.04 to 20.04?

Tags: upgrade, 19.04, 20.04

With the new release of 20.04 LTS. How can I upgrade my 19.04 to this newest version? Or do I have to upgrade to 19.10 first?

Comment: Run `update-manager -d` in the terminal.

Comment: I would re-install using 'something else', use your existing partitions and **not** format your partitions. Installer (`ubiquity`) will note your additional packages (added post-install), wipe system directories then install your new system, adding back earlier noted packages (if available for new release) and take a fraction of the time of a *release-upgrade*.  It only erases user files if you select format, however you should still backup first.

Comment: This is the best solution so far, given the current state of the update URLs

https://www.1f433.net/notes/ubuntu-an-upgrade-from-disco-to-focal-is-not-supported-with-this-tool/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out this link on how to do it: https://www.howtogeek.com/351360/how-to-upgrade-to-the-latest-version-of-ubuntu/

Yes you will have to upgrade to 19.10 first I believe.
Basically, here's the steps:

1. Since ubuntu normally only tells you to upgrade when there is an LTS version out, you will need to change that in order to prevent any problem during the installation.
   Use your preferred editor and type:
   `sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`
   At the bottom, you should see the text `prompt=lts`. If you see that, change the `lts` to `normal`. However if you don't see it you are good.
2. run the command
   `do-release-upgrade -c`
   This command checks Ubuntu’s servers for any available updates and informs you which version of Ubuntu you’ll be upgrading to.
3. The previous command checks for available updates, and if you see the current update that you want to upgrade to, execute the command, `sudo do-release-upgrade`.
4. Just follow along with what the command lines tell you and you should be good to go!

I apologise for the unconventional styling of this answer, I am new and don't quite know the syntaxes yet.
For the most accurate answer check the link I put at the top.

Comment: Doesn't work nowadays unfortunately :( I have `Prompt=normal`. `do-release-upgrade -c` outputs `New release '20.04.1 LTS' available.` but when I run the upgrade it says "Can not upgrade

An upgrade from 'disco' to 'focal' is not supported with this tool."

Comment: same error im getting too.