# Cannot upgrade from 19.4 to 20.4 since 19.4 is no longer supported

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

When I run `sudo do-release-upgrade` what I get is `An upgrade from 'disco' to 'focal' is not supported with this tool.` I have been looking here [How can one upgrade Ubuntu 19.04 to 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230498/how-can-one-upgrade-ubuntu-19-04-to-20-04), but the solution says 'upgrade to 19.10 first'. That doesn't work since the command to upgrade is what is not working. The solution in [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) is also not working for the same reason.

What is the way to go? Is it possible or should I forget about it an install a the 20.4 version from scratch and install everything again?

Comment: You may want to backup your data in the `/home` folder and do a clean install of 20.04. Next time do not wait till after your installation has reached its "end of life" to upgrade to the next version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade from 18.10 to 19.10, using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208109/how-to-upgrade-from-18-10-to-19-10-using-the-command-line) Although this question was about upgrading from 18.10 to 19.10, it can be adopted for upgrading 19.04 to 20.04 after replacing `cosmic` with `disco`, `disco` with `eoan` and `eoan` with `focal`.